# Reordering (not sorting) an associative array?

Tags: php, arrays

Lets say, I have this array:

```
['key1'] => 'value1'

['key3'] => 'value3'

['key2'] => 'value2'

['key4'] => 'value4'
```

How can I put key2 after key1?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you only want to put key2 after key1 or is there other reordering that would take place?

Answer (score 2):

```
['key1'] => 'value1'

['key3'] => 'value3'

['key2'] => 'value2'

['key4'] => 'value4'
```

you can use `ksort` for this purpose.

`ksort` sorts the array on basis of key and return `true` on success.

further you can pass `$sort_flags` as per your sorting requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If that is all you are wanting to do you could use ksort. This sorts an array by key while maintaining the data.

[ksort](https://www.php.net/ksort)

```
$test = array("key1"=>"value1","key3"=>"value3","key2"=>"value2","key4"=>"value4");
ksort($test);
print_r($test);
```

returns

Array ( [key1] => value1 [key2] => value2 [key3] => value3 [key4] => value4 )